# Decimals translated by browser when a dropdown is used

Tags: browser, internationalization

The dot is removed by the browser and results in a value of 25 if you choose 0.25 (hence the error below).

[image: dot gets removed by the browser]

The example config with listitems results in a dropdown in TFS. This works fine in Firefox. Chrome and Internet Explorer remove the dot and e.g. transform the value 0.5 to 5

```
<FIELD name="Effort" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" type="Double" reportable="measure" formula="sum">
    <HELPTEXT>The estimated effort to implemented the backlog item</HELPTEXT>
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
        <LISTITEM value="0" />
        <LISTITEM value="0.25" />
        <LISTITEM value="0.5" />
        <LISTITEM value="1" />
        <LISTITEM value="2" />
        <LISTITEM value="3" />
        <LISTITEM value="5" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
</FIELD>
```

It can be solved for Internet Explorer by putting English as language preference, but that is not a solution since most of our users have set Dutch. Setting the dot as a decimal separator isn't a solution either, because Dutch uses a comma for that.

[image]

How can I solve this without bothering the end user?

Comment: It's only in Effort field? in other fields don't you have any values with 'dot'?

Comment: The same happens with other fields if the type is Double. You can however set decimal values manually. The problem occurs when Allowedvalues is used.

Comment: Which version of TFS do you use? Test on TFS 2018 update2, cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: TFS 2017 update 3

Comment: @Kokkie Tested on TFS 2017 update3, still cannot reproduce this issue, everything works as expected. Can your reproduce this issue on other machines? Suggest you cleaning the caches on your client browser, then try it again.

Comment: Thanks Andy, but unfortunately it also occurs on other machines (the complain actually came from a colleague). Cleaning the cache didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone from Microsoft found the issue and they are solving it;
*"FYI, we found this to be an issue with localization. We are fixing it "*

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a control field .Please follow this tutorial it will surely help you.
Click here [Control field numberFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/control-xml-element-reference?view=tfs-2015)

or you can also try my sample

```
<Control Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort"  Label="Rough Estimation:" LabelPosition="Left" NumberFormat="DecimalNumbers" />
```

Feel free to ask if it not work .Thanks

Comment: Did you try this approach?

Comment: The page you refer to is for TFS 2015 | TFS 2013, while we currently use TFS 2017